# Can't properly detect CapsLock key state

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, key, raw-input

My `RawInput` implementation for keyboard logging can't detect whether the **CapsLock** key is tooggled to return a mayus or minus character using the `ToUnicodeEx` function.

I will describe what happens, is something strange...

If I run the app with the **CapsLock** key enabled, then it is detected as enabled, always, even when I disable the key after the program is running, at execution time.

If I run the app with the **CapsLock** key disabled, then it is detected as disabled, always, even when I enable the key after the program is running, at execution time.

So, for example If I run the app with the **CapsLock** key enabled, this value always will be True even when I disable the key after the app ran:

```
Dim isCapsLockPress As Boolean = 
    ((CUShort(InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetKeyState(Keys.Capital)) And &HFFFF) <> 0)
```

This is the relevant code, If I need to show any other definition please comment it.

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Processes WM_INPUT messages to retrieve information about any keyboard events that occur.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="message">
''' The WM_INPUT message to process.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub ProcessInputCommand(ByVal message As Message)

    Dim dwSize As UInteger = 0

    ' First call to GetRawInputData sets the value of dwSize,
    ' which can then be used to allocate the appropriate amount of memory, storing the pointer in "buffer".
    InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetRawInputData(message.LParam,
                                              NativeMethods.GetRawInputDataCommand.Input,
                                              IntPtr.Zero,
                                              dwSize,
                                              CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputHeader))))

    Dim buffer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(CInt(dwSize))

    Try
        ' Check that buffer points to something, 
        ' and if so, call GetRawInputData again to fill the allocated memory with information about the input.
        If (buffer <> IntPtr.Zero) AndAlso
           (InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetRawInputData(message.LParam,
                                                      NativeMethods.GetRawInputDataCommand.Input,
                                                      buffer,
                                                      dwSize,
                                                      CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputHeader)))) = dwSize) Then

            ' Store the message information in "raw", 
            ' then check that the input comes from a keyboard device before processing it to raise an appropriate KeyPressed event.
            Dim raw As InputDevice.NativeMethods.Rawinput =
                CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, GetType(InputDevice.NativeMethods.Rawinput)), InputDevice.NativeMethods.Rawinput)

            If raw.Header.DwType = NativeMethods.DeviceType.Keyboard Then

                ' Filter for Key Down events and then retrieve informationabout the keystroke.
                If (raw.Keyboard.Message = InputDevice.NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_KEYDOWN) OrElse
                   (raw.Keyboard.Message = InputDevice.NativeMethods.WindowsMessages.WM_SYSKEYDOWN) Then

                    Dim key As UShort = raw.Keyboard.VKey

                    ' On most keyboards, "extended" keys such as the arrow or page keys return two codes: 
                    ' 1: the key 's own code, and 2: a "extended key" flag, which translates to 255. 
                    ' The flag isn't useful to us, so it can be disregarded.
                    If key > VKLastKey Then
                        Return
                    End If

                    Dim isShiftPress As Boolean = (InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) <> 0)
                    Dim isCapsLockPress As Boolean = ((CUShort(InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetKeyState(Keys.Capital)) And &HFFFF) <> 0)
                    Dim isAltGrPress As Boolean = (InputDevice.NativeMethods.GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Menu) <> 0)

                    ' Retrieve information about the device and the key that was pressed.
                    Dim dInfo As DeviceInfo = CType(deviceList(raw.Header.HDevice), DeviceInfo)
                    dInfo.KeyNum = key
                    dInfo.Key = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(Keys), [Enum].GetName(GetType(Keys), key)), Keys)
                    dInfo.Character = Me.GetCharsFromKeys(dInfo.Key,
                                                          isShiftPress Or isCapsLockPress,
                                                          isAltGrPress)

                    ' If the key that was pressed is valid and there was no problem retrieving information on the device,
                    ' raise the KeyPressed event.
                    If (KeyPressedEvent IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (dInfo IsNot Nothing) Then
                        RaiseEvent KeyPressed(Me, New KeyPressedEventArgs(dInfo, Me.GetDevice(message.LParam.ToInt32())))

                    Else
                        Throw New ApplicationException(String.Format("Received Unknown Key: {0}. Possibly an unknown device.", key))

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Finally
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Function GetCharsFromKeys(ByVal key As Keys,
                                  ByVal shift As Boolean,
                                  ByVal altGr As Boolean) As String

    Dim buf As New StringBuilder(256)
    Dim keyboardState As Byte() = New Byte(255) {}

    If shift Then
        keyboardState(CInt(Keys.ShiftKey)) = &HFF
    End If

    If altGr Then
        keyboardState(CInt(Keys.ControlKey)) = &HFF
        keyboardState(CInt(Keys.Menu)) = &HFF
    End If

    Dim rc As Integer
    Do ' Remove dead characters. 
        rc = InputDevice.NativeMethods.ToUnicodeEx(CUInt(key), 0UI, keyboardState, buf, 256, 0UI,
                                                   Me.KeyboardLayoutHandle)
    Loop While rc < 0

    Return buf.ToString()

End Function
```

> EDIT:

When constructing the `RawInputDevice` structure, I noted that for the `dwFlags` parameter if I remove the `NoLegacy` flag solves the problem, however, I'm not sure if that will cause another strange behavior, so, it's right just to remove this flag here?:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

    ' Create an array of all the raw input devices we want to listen to. 
    ' In this case, only keyboard devices.
    Dim rid As InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputDevice() =
        New InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputDevice(0) {}

    With rid(0)
        .UsUsagePage = 1US
        .UsUsage = 6US
        .HwndTarget = hwnd
        .DwFlags = InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputDeviceFlags.NoLegacy Or
                   InputDevice.NativeMethods.RawInputDeviceFlags.InputSink

    End With

    If Not InputDevice.NativeMethods.RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, CUInt(rid.Length), CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(rid(0)))) Then
        Throw New ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).")
    End If

    Me.deviceCountB = EnumerateDevices()

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `&HFFFF` and not `1` for "is it down" and `H80` for "is it toggled"?

Comment: As @CodesInChaos said but the opposite. For `key down` is `1000 0000` in binary or `H80` in hex and for toggled `0000 0001` which is `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I fixed that. but with `Control.IsKeyLocked` I have exactly the same problem. I think the real problem was the `NoLegacy` flag that I mentioned in my update, once removed it worked fine. thanks anyways!

Comment: anyways please feel free to post that fix as an answer to accept the answer.